# IndexError when filling multi-dimensional array with find_by_name

Tags: python, arrays

can you help me with python multi-dimensional array? This is my scenario I have an array of fields and an array of values which contains an array of values. Here is my code

```
late_payment_fields = ['latePaymentFee', 'latePaymentFeePer', 
                       'latePaymentFeeMax', 'latePaymentFeeMin']

payment_values = [['0', '0', '0', '10'], ['0', '0', '0', '10'],
                  ['10', '0', '5', '0'], ['', '101', '0', '0'],
                  ['10', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '10', '12', '0']]
```

As you can see I have 4 fields and an array of payment_values. What I'm trying to do here is that I am going to assign to those fields the 6 sets of values one set at a time. This is for a testing I'm doing. So this is how I assigned the values to the fields a set a time.

```
def fillLatePaymentfields ():
    for i in payment_values:
    for index in range(len(payment_values)):
        browser.find_by_name(late_payment_fields[index]).fill(i[index])
        logger(f, 'Adding values to' + late_payment_fields[index])
    browser.find_by_id('utbFrmDiv').find_by_tag('a').first.click()
    errorChecking('', 'late_payment')
```

The problem is I got an error message saying

> "browser.find_by_name(late_payment_fields[index]).fill(i[index]) IndexError: index out of range"

Can someone tell me why is it out of range?

Comment: This code doesn't even run. It fails in bytecode compilation with an IndentationError.

Comment: it is properly indented in my code, i just did not notice that it was not indented properly after i paste the code here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in payment_values:
    for index in range(len(payment_values)):
```

Surely `len(payment_values)` here should be `len(i)`? P.S. Can we get a better name for `i`?

Answer (score 0):

`range(len(payment_values))` means `range(6)`.

so `late_payment_fields[5]` throw error.

try a chip code

```py
late_payment_fields = ['latePaymentFee', 'latePaymentFeePer',
                       'latePaymentFeeMax', 'latePaymentFeeMin']

payment_values = [['0', '0', '0', '10'], ['0', '0', '0', '10'],
                  ['10', '0', '5', '0'], ['', '101', '0', '0'],
                  ['10', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '10', '12', '0']]

def fillLatePaymentfields():
    indexes_of_payment_fields = range(len(late_payment_fields))
    for payment in payment_values:
        for index in indexes_of_payment_fields:
            print late_payment_fields[index], (payment[index])
            print 'Adding values to ' + late_payment_fields[index]

fillLatePaymentfields()
```